# Pre-populating Room using Koin and DB Browser

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-database, koin

I need to pre-populate a table in Room using a .csv file.
I saw in https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate that I needed a .db file instead so I used DB Browser to import my .csv and create a .db file.
I added my .db file to folder /assets and created an abstract class for my database, a dao and a data class, then added it in Koin using .createFromAsset.
It's not creating anything though (I am checking in App Inspection). Not throwing any errors. Nothing.
The .csv has around 20k entries.

**This is my abstract class**

```
@Database(entities = [PlantInfo::class], version = 1)
abstract class PlantInfoDB: RoomDatabase(){
    abstract fun plantInfoDao(): PlantInfoDao
}
```

**This is my DAO**

```
@Dao
interface PlantInfoDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM PlantInfo")
    fun getAllPlantInfo(): List<PlantInfo>
}
```

**This is my Data Class**

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "PlantInfo")
data class PlantInfo(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "scientificName") val scientificName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "commonName") val commonName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "family") val family: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cultivation") val cultivation: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "light") val light: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "water") val water: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "disease") val disease: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "img") val img: String
) : Parcelable
```

**My KoinGraph**

```
object KoinGraph {

    val mainModule = module {

        single {
            Room.databaseBuilder(get(), PlantInfoDB::class.java, "PlantInfo")
            .createFromAsset("plants_db.db")
            .build()
        }

      single {
            Room.databaseBuilder(get(), AppDB::class.java, "AppDB")
                .build()
        }

        single { get<AppDB>().waterDao() }
        single { get<AppDB>().plantDao() }
        single { get<PlantInfoDB>().plantInfoDao() }
        factory { WaterAlarm(get()) }
        single { WaterRepository() }
        single { PlantIdRepository() }
        single { RandomQuotesRepository() }
        viewModel { SearchByPictureViewModel(get()) }
        viewModel { AddPlantPictureViewModel() }
        viewModel { HomePlantViewModel(get(), get()) }
        viewModel { PlantFormViewModel(get()) }
    }
}
```

This is my DB Browser file structure

```
CREATE TABLE "PlantInfo" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "scientificName"    TEXT,
    "commonName"    TEXT,
    "family"    TEXT,
    "description"   TEXT,
    "cultivation"   TEXT,
    "light" INTEGER,
    "water" INTEGER,
    "disease"   TEXT,
    "img"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
)
```

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can also use CSV file . its data and u have parse it and insert all the data in DB on first launch  . With `.db` file u can follow Steps https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate.

Comment: I checked how to pre-populate directly with a csv but didn't find anything. I saw that in the official documentation they use .db that's why I thought it was mandatory.